# Create virtual block device which writes to /dev/null

Tags: linux, networking, block-device, null

I want to test some physical links in a setup. The software tooling that I can use to test this require a block device to read/write from/to. The block devices I have available can't saturate the physical link so I can't fully test it.

I know I can setup a virtual block device which is backed by a file. So my idea was to somehow setup a virtual block device to /dev/null but the problem is of course that I can't read from it. Is there a way I could setup a virtual block device that writes to /dev/null but just returns always zero when read?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You could also see if this looks interesting to you https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/null_blk.txt

Comment: Being that the context seems to be Linux and this is a highly OS-specific (kernel-specific) question, I added `linux` tag. Please feel free to remove if this is in error, or add other tags as appropriate.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Device-mapper#Zero

> See Documentation/device-mapper/zero.txt for usage. This target has no target-specific parameters.
>
> The "zero" target create that functions similarly to /dev/zero: All reads return binary zero, and all writes are discarded. Normally used in tests [...]
>
> This creates a 1GB (1953125-sector) zero target:
>
> ```
> root# dmsetup create 1gb-zero --table '0 1953125 zero'
> ```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need it to have a specific limited size, you can just use `/dev/zero` directly.  Technically it's a character device, not block.

**`/dev/zero` discards writes like `/dev/null` but reads as zero instead of EOF.**

As documented in [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html), on Linux you can make your own under any name with
`mknod -m 666 /dev/zero c 1 5` Or of course make a symlink to `/dev/zero`.